# Angular 2 rc5 unexpected token < parse HTML to varaible

Tags: http, angular, service, jsonp

I have a jsonp call that returns HTML. In console I can see the returned document but I believe its expecting javascript and since the first "<" in < div > is not javascript it throws an error. How do you parse it correctly into a variable? I will use this variable in the view as < div [innerHTML]="variable" >

```
public getToolTip(item: any) {
    let url = 'http://us.battle.net/wow/en/item/138154/scenario-normal/tooltip?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK';
    this.jsonp.get(url)
              .map((res:any) => res)
              .subscribe(res => this.template = res);
}
```

I also tried using DOMParser but same issue of unexpected token '<'

```
public getToolTip(item: any) {
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let url = 'http://us.battle.net/wow/en/item/138154/scenario-normal/tooltip?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK';
    this.jsonp.get(url)
              .map((res:any) =>  res = parser.parseFromString(res, 'text/html'))
              .subscribe(res => this.template = res);
}
```

[Image of Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY374.png)

If i click on "callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished" from console, the html document i want is returned properly, just it isnt saved to a variable correctly

[Request / Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUt9W.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a mistake here:

```
.map((res:any) => res)
```

It should be:

```
.map((res:any) => res.json())
```

Comment: I removed .json() to see if that would change anything but I went ahead and put it back just to see. but that doesn't solve the problem :[

Comment: Please, add whole code from component and template so I can debug.

Comment: Actually, you can not use json() because it's not an json. The url you are hitting is returning html.